# android question about service and the method onstartcommand

Tags: android, service

In a service class there is a method to start the service. If that service gets done executing does it runs onstartcommand from the beginning? Is onstartcommand sorta like a loop as long as the service is running.  For example i have

```
onStartCommand {
  int x = 0;
  if(x == 0){

  } else {
  }
}
```

After that is complete does it run it again. If you know that answer please explain. I have read google explanation of services and it did not explain that part very well. Is onstartcommand sorta like a loop as long as the service is runnning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't. onstartcommand is run once. If you want to do something that takes long or does something recursively, you probably want to create a thread to do the hard job and just return from onStartCommand().